# Which logic is better for implementing exception logging ( Particularly in case of logging not in case of regular string formatting )?

Tags: python, logging

In python, i have a logging mechanism setup which will catch all the errors and exceptions to a file.

Logic - 1

```
logger.info('Running get_all_files_from_cmc')
    try:
        pipe.get_all_files_from_cmc()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception('Get_all_files_from_cmc Failed {}'.format(e))
```

Logic -2

```
logger.info('Running get_all_files_from_cmc')
    try:
        pipe.get_all_files_from_cmc()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception('Get_all_files_from_cmc Failed' + e)
```

Logic - 3

```
logger.info('Running get_all_files_from_cmc')
        try:
            pipe.get_all_files_from_cmc()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception('Get_all_files_from_cmc Failed')
```

Which of the two logics is correct to implement as formatting inside the logging is it wrong?

Or Logic -3 because logging handles the `e` value automatically.?

Comment: Both are valid (or _correct_, if you make sure to convert the Exception to a string manually). For even more options, have a look at the Python documentation for [output formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

Comment: Since `logger.exception` adds the exception info automatically, why are you concatenating `e` at all…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic 3 is best - because you are using `exception()`, the exception traceback will be stored in the log. You only need to indicate what operation failed, which your Logic 3 does.

Answer (score 4):

`.format()` is proper way to do it because if you try to concatenate (`+`) `'Get_all_files_from_cmc Failed'` with  anything other than `str` it would cause another error.

Comment: Indeed, and to be clear, `e` is not `str` in this case

Comment: @Chris_Rands You are correct , I was just presenting the general rule.